# Improve on search and archive time in GitHub Actions PowerShell

Tags: powershell, performance, recursion, filtering, get-childitem

Below is my workflow on PowerShell that searches for files and folders provided as a comma-separated list to `itemsToInclude`:

```yaml
      $zipFileName = "${{ github.workspace }}\package-$env:GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER.zip"

      cd "${{ github.workspace }}"

      $itemsToInclude = $env:INPUTS_FILESINZIP

      Write-Host "itemsToInclude is- $itemsToInclude"

 

      if (-not (Test-Path $zipFileName)) {

        $null = New-Item $zipFileName -ItemType File

      }

      $workspace = "${{ github.workspace }}"

      # Define the directories to exclude

      $excludeDirectories = @('DevOps')
      $excludeExtensions = @('.java', '.class')


      # Include specific files and folders as per the comma-separated list

      Write-Host 'Include specific files and folders as per the comma-separated list'

      $itemsToIncludeList = $itemsToInclude -split ','
      $filesToInclude = Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File  -Exclude $excludeDirectories | Where-Object {
      $itemName = $_.Name

      Write-Host "Checking file: $itemName"

      $itemsToIncludeList -contains $itemName

      }

 
      $filesToInclude | ForEach-Object {

        $newZipEntrySplat = @{

          EntryPath   = $_.FullName.Substring($workspace.Length)
          SourcePath  = $_.FullName
          Destination = $zipFileName

          }

          Write-Host "Adding file: $($_.FullName)"
          New-ZipEntry @newZipEntrySplat

        }

      Write-Host "Zip file created: $zipFileName"

    env:
      INPUTS_FILESINZIP: ${{ inputs.filesinzip }}
```

The time it takes to search for desired files and include them in ZIP is more than acceptable.

Thus, I wish to exclude the folder `DevOps` and all files having extensions `.java` and `.class` so the time taken for this step is reduced.

Unfortunately, the `-Exclude` option does not work and I can see all files inside the AreDevOps folder listed in the output for `Checking file:`

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to **exclude an entire directory *subtree* from enumeration from a recursive [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call with `-Exclude`**.

Unfortunately, this is ***not* directly supported in *Windows PowerShell* and still not as of [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) 7.4**:

- The **`-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters** **operate on item** (file or directory) ***names* only** (not on *paths*).
- They **only operate on the matching items *themselves***. That is, **if a *directory*'s name matches, *its subtree is still recursed into***.

[GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159) is a **feature request** to also support excluding the entire *subtrees* of matching subdirectories.

---

###### Workarounds:

If the **subdirectories whose subtrees you want to exclude** are all ***top-level*, i.e. *immediate child items* of the target directory**, you can use a two-step approach:

```
$filesToInclude = 
  Get-ChildItem $workspace -Exclude $excludeDirectories |
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Exclude $excludeExtensions
```

- The first `Get-ChildItem` call returns only top-level items that do not match the name, thereby excluding the directories of interest.
- The second call then only recurses on the non-excluded items, using filename-extension exclusions.

---

If you need to **exclude the subtrees of directories matching given names *on any level of the input subtree***, you will need ***post-filtering*, which results in much slower execution**:

```
# Construct a regex from the exclusion patterns.
# NOTE: The individual patterns must be
#   * either: *literal* names, such as 'DevOps'
#     * for [ and ] to be used *literally*, escape them as \[ and \]
#   * or: *regexes* rather than *wildcard* patterns; e.g.:
#     * instead of 'Foo*', use 'Foo.*?'
#     * instead of 'Foo?', use 'Foo.'
$regex = 
  '(?<=^|[\\/])(?:{0})(?=[\\/]|$)' -f ($excludeDirectories -join '|')

$filesToInclude =
  & {
    # Output the target directory itself, alone.
    Get-Item $workspace  
    # Recurse over subdirectories only and exclude matching subtrees.
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory $workspace |
      Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch $regex } 
  } | # Now enumerate all files in the non-excluded directories.
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Exclude $excludeExtensions
```

- The approach is a two-step one again:

  - First, enumerate *subdirectories* only, and exclude the unwanted subtrees, resulting in a list of directories of interest only.
  - Then, in each directory of interest, recursively look for *files* of interest.
  - Note: The assumption is that there are (far) fewer directories than files, so that first eliminating entire subdirectory trees is more efficient than walking the *entire* tree and having to examine each file's path.
- The use of a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) is needed to rule out false positives, and also enables more efficient matching with *multiple* exclusions, due to using only a *single* [`-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/On8Jut/1):

    - The linked page demonstrates a regex based on the following array of exclusion patterns: `$excludeDirectories = 'DevOps', 'obj', 'bin'`
    - Among the sample input paths shown, the ones with a pattern highlighted are the ones that the `-notmatch` operation would eliminate.